# Getting a 'Connection refused: connect' error because parseInt in Java Socket after passing data to the server from client?

Tags: java, sockets, server, client

I was trying to pass from the client to the server an `Integer` so in the Server class I could use that integer as a parameter for my fibonacci function. The thing is that the program was running perfectly fine and the connections were well stablished before adding the following lines:

```
String transformedData = data.toString();
int transformedInt = Integer.parseInt(transformedData);
                
int result = fibonacci(transformedInt);
```

So I don't know why I'm getting the error (below) when I pass ANY string from the client to the server

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:503)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:492)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:333)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:648)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:597)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:520)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:294)
    at ajHomeWork1/cop2805.Client.main(Client.java:14)
```

Also, I'm new to the socket programming in java so I really don't know if what I did to transform the byte data to Integer is the proper way to do it for this program

Server class:

```
public class Server {
        
    static int fibonacci(int numb) // Recursive Fibonacci
    {
        if (numb <= 1)
            return numb;
        return fibonacci(numb-1) + fibonacci(numb-2);
    }
         
        
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
        ServerSocket server = null;
        boolean shutdown = false;
        
        
        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(1238);
            System.out.println("Port bound. Accepting Conncetions");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        
        while(!shutdown) {
            Socket client = null;
            InputStream input = null;
            OutputStream output = null;
            
            try {
                client = server.accept();
                input = client.getInputStream();
                output = client.getOutputStream();
                
                int n = input.read();
                byte[] data = new byte[n];
                String transformedData = data.toString();
                int transformedInt = Integer.parseInt(transformedData);
                
                int result = fibonacci(transformedInt); 
                input.read(data);
                
                String clientInput = new String(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                clientInput.replace("\n", "");
                System.out.println("Client said " + clientInput);
                
                String response = "Your input was [" + clientInput + "]" + " Fibonacci result of " + transformedInt + " is : " + result;
                output.write(response.length());
                output.write(response.getBytes());
                
                client.close();
                if(clientInput.equalsIgnoreCase("shutdown")) {
                    System.out.println("Shutting down....");
                    shutdown = true;
                }
            }
            
            catch (IOException e) { 
                e.printStackTrace();
                continue;
                
            }
        }

    }
}
```

And this is the client class:

```
public class Client {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Input an int : ");
        BufferedReader userInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try {
            String userString = userInput.readLine();
            Socket connection = new Socket("127.0.0.1",1238);
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream();
            
            output.write(userString.length());
            output.write(userString.getBytes());
            
            int n = input.read();
            byte[] data = new byte[n];
            input.read(data);
            
            String serverResponse = new String(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            System.out.println("Server said: " + serverResponse);
            
            if(!connection.isClosed())
                connection.close();
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, int n is the variable that is storing the input that the client is sending to the server, byte[] data is extracting the information from the input so it can send it as a byte to the server and finally transformedData string is transforming (inside the server) the data that was passed so I can use it as a parameter for the fibonacci function

Comment: Yeah, I'm creating that variable to pass it to the serverResponse, which requires a byte array as parameter

Comment: There are several logic errors in the way both client and server are treating data. But none of that can cause the error in question. A "Connection refused" error means the `new Socket("127.0.0.1",1238)` statement is failing before any data can be exchanged. The error means the client is not able to connect to the server at all.

Comment: Yes Remy, that would be the second main thing that I'm aiming to fix, because I really don't know how to pass the parameter from the client to the server so the fibonacci function can use it to return me my result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several logic errors in the way that both client and server are treating data. But mishandling of data after the connection is established cannot cause a "Connection refused" error. That error means the `new Socket("127.0.0.1",1238)` statement in the client is failing before any data can be exchanged. Which means the client is not able to connect to the server at all, either because:

- the IP/Port is wrong, or there is no server listening on the IP/port.
- the server's backlog of pending connections is full.
- a firewall/antivirus is blocking the connection.

Once you address that and can establish a connection correctly, then try something more like the following regarding the data exchange:

Server class:

```
public class Server {

    static int fibonacci(int numb) // Recursive Fibonacci
    {
        if (numb <= 1)
            return numb;
        return fibonacci(numb-1) + fibonacci(numb-2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {    

        ServerSocket server = null;
        boolean shutdown = false;   

        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(1238);
            System.out.println("Port bound. Accepting Conncetions");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        while (!shutdown) {
            try {
                Socket client = server.accept();
                DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(client.getInputStream()));
                DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(client.getOutputStream()));

                int n = input.readInt();
                byte[] data = new byte[n];
                input.readFully(data);

                String clientInput = new String(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                clientInput.replace("\n", "");

                System.out.println("Client said " + clientInput);
                String response;

                if (clientInput.equalsIgnoreCase("shutdown"))
                {
                    System.out.println("Shutting down....");
                    response = "Shutting down";
                    shutdown = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    int transformedInt = Integer.parseInt(clientInput);
                    int result = fibonacci(transformedInt); 
                    response = "Your input was [" + clientInput + "] Fibonacci result of " + Integer.toString(transformedInt) + " is : " + Integer.toString(result);
                }

                data = response.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                output.writeInt(data.length());
                output.write(data, 0, data.length());
                output.flush();

                client.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) { 
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Client class:

```
public class Client {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Input an int : ");
        BufferedReader userInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try {
            String userString = userInput.readLine();

            Socket connection = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1238);
            DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream()));
            DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream()));
            
            bytes[] data = userString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            output.writeInt(data.length());
            output.write(data, 0, data.length());
            output.flush();
            
            int n = input.readInt();
            data = new byte[n];
            input.readFully(data);
            
            String serverResponse = new String(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            System.out.println("Server said: " + serverResponse);
            
            connection.close();
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```